# Can't scrape some links using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I got a weird error. I can't scrape link https://www.example.com/2/

But, I can scrape link https://www.example.com/922/

**P.S.** I am not using the real link since I am not allowed by my job. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to debug it using command `scrapy view https://www.example.com/2/`, it shows the correct HTML I am expecting. When I check the URL via Chrome inspector, it turns out it gives the correct HTML but gives error 500 status instead of 200. I solved it using `handle_httpstatus_list = [500]` in my spider.

Comment: 500 simply means website is having internal troubles and can't serve content. Adding 500 to handles status list will just allow you to parse those status 500 pages that are most likely empty.

Comment: In this case, it's not empty. Try running `scrapy view https://www.websiteclosers.com/website-view/website/2/`, you'll see. Yeah, it's weird. I know. I don't know what is wrong with their server.